# The definition of a graph's transitive reduction

Tags: algorithms, graphs, directed-graphs

I want to determine the transitive reduction of this graph:

[image: 1]

as of now, I only found the first step of doing this: represent the transitive closure of the graph as an adjacency relation, so this is what I did:

```
 (a,b)
 (a,c)
 (a,d)
 (a,e)
 (b,d)
 (c,d)
 (c,e)
 (d,e)
```

I'm not sure that this is the correct transitive closure of the graph, and I don't know how to move forward in determining its transitive reduction.

Comment: You are missing $(b,e)$.

Answer (score 1):

If we order the vertices alphabetically, then the adjacency matrix is

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

The adjacency matrix of the transitive closure would be

$$B=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&1&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

To get the this one you get each row by navigate the graph starting at the node corresponding to that row and mark with a $1$ the columns of the nodes that you manage to visit and with $0$ the rest.

Now,

$$AB=\begin{pmatrix}
0&0&0&2&3\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

To build the adjacency matrix $C$ of the transitive reduction put a $1$ in position $(i,j)$ if the $(i,j)$ entry of $A$ is non-zero and the $(i,j)$ entry of $AB$ is zero.

So, the adjacency matrix of the transitive reduction should be

$$C=\begin{pmatrix}
0&1&1&0&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&1&0\\
0&0&0&0&1\\
0&0&0&0&0
\end{pmatrix}$$

So, the transitive reduction looks like this

[image]